# Python matplotlib return only object instead of plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using vscdoe for python. When I do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
```

it will give me a blank plot. However, when I use

```
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6])
```

in subsequent block, I got a

```
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f9f118e68b0>
```

My question is: how can I get the vscode print my plot?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `pyplot.show()`?

Comment: sorry for the delay, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `plt.show()` right now you're not printing any of your graph out.

#### Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6])
plt.show() # this line displays your graph
```

#### Customize the graph

Now that you know how to print out the graph you could add a title and axises labels.

```py
plt.ylabel('some numbers') # y-axis title
plt.xlabel('other numbers') # x-axis title
plt.title('My Graph') # main title
plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add [`pyplot.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6])

pyplot.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually do it. It prints out in a nice size!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6])

plt.show()
```